# How to install thirdparty library to a filesystem prefix

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-package, filesystem, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use a python library provided by Gumstix Robovero in ROS.

I looked through the [Using ThirdPartyLibraries](http://www.ros.org/wiki/UsingThirdPartyLibraries) and I guess I may need to [Wrapping External Library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Wrapping%20External%20Libraries).
In [Wrapping External Library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Wrapping%20External%20Libraries), It says "for ROS Fuerte(and Groovy I guess), the best practice is to no longer wrap thirdparty libraries and instead install to a filesystem prefix using catkin". I am using Groovy right now, but I am not very familiar with catkin and actually I don't understand filesystem prefix. For [Wrapping External Library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Wrapping%20External%20Libraries), I know the basic idea is to create a ROS package that compiles the third-party library code and makes it available using rosbuild's dependency system. But in Groovy, how can I install thirdparty libraries to a filesystem prefix?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52483/how-to-install-thirdparty-library-to-a-filesystem-prefix/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended solution is to use [bloom](http://ros-infrastructure.github.com/bloom/doc)

There's a tutorial at the bottom for releasing "non-catkin" libraries.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0